# Counting how many columns and rows in table of html file

Tags: c#, .net, html, winforms, count

How can we find how many columns and rows are there in the html file ? How can we count that how many td tags are there in the html file ?

Comment: You might change your title to say, how many table columns and rows. When I first saw it, I thought you were talking characters over, characters down, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [HTML Agility pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to parse the HTML, then query it for the number of `<TR>` tags for the number of rows in a table.

For the `<TD>`, use the first row and get the number of those. Check if there are any `colspan` attributes and add the value of each - 1, to get the number of columns in the table.

For example, to get the number of rows:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");

// Assuming only one table in the file
int colums = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//tr").Count();
```

Comment: How do I extract the content from html table using HTML Agility pack,what type of code I should write to extract the content column by column from html table ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way in HTML to count the `<TD>` rows/columns I'm afraid. You're best bet would be to get a program like Notepad++ and literally "search" for `<TD` and see how many results appear. Or you could go down the Javascript route - but that's a different kettle of fish ;)

Comment: OP is using C# and .NET, not asking about how to do so in HTML. It's a little vague, but it's in the tags.